# How can I have multiple responses from a single endpoint with different parameters?

Tags: apiary.io, apiblueprint

We are looking at using the API Blueprint.  There are cases where we would like one request to return a proper response and another request to return an 'error' response such as a `400 bad request` so that other developers can work against the mock API on apiary.io with both types of responses and handle it in their applications.

I've created a completely arbitrary example below,

```
## Thing [/thing/{id}]
Gets a thing but the thing id must be a prime number!


+ Parameters
    + id (string) ... ID of the thing, a prime number!

+ Model (application/json)

    The thing itself.

    + Body

            {
                "description": "It is green"
            }

### Retrieve a Single Gist [GET]
+ Response 200

    [Gist][]
```

Now somehow I would like to add in a response for `/thing/40`

```
+ Response 400
    {  "error" : "Invalid request" }
```

But I am not sure how I would do this with the API Blueprint.  This was achievable under the 'old' style on apiary.io but we'd like to move on to the new syntax

Answer (score 12):

To document multiple responses simply add it after the `Response 200` like so:

```
## Thing [/thing/{id}]
Gets a thing but the thing id must be a prime number!

+ Parameters
    + id (string) ... ID of the thing, a prime number!

+ Model (application/json)

    The thing itself.

    + Body

            {
                "description": "It is green"
            }

### Retrieve a Single Gist [GET]
+ Response 200

    [Thing][]

+ Response 400 (application/json)

        {  "error" : "Invalid request" }
```

Note there is currently no dedicated syntax to discuss the conditions (when this response i s returned). You can discuss it anyway you like it for example:

```
+ Response 400 (application/json)

    This response is returned when no `Thing` for given `id` exists.

    + Body
```

If you are using Apiary mock, keep in mind that the first response listed is returned by default, unless you say otherwise using the [prefer HTTP header](http://support.apiary.io/forums/120125-general/suggestions/3264498-match-on-request-headers).

Comment: I see - so I can't specifically create a description/response for /thing/40.  Could I submit a feature request for this somewhere?

Comment: Not in a structured way. You can only comment on it "by mouth". May I ask you what is your use-case / why do you need it?

Comment: Plan is to add support for it in a future revision of API Blueprint mainly to improve testability of a blueprint – https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues/21, https://gist.github.com/zdne/01e287fe18d232672d43#new-payload-structure-in-1b You can see & contribute to API Blueprint roadmap at https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues/milestones

Comment: Multiple request/response pairs are now available as ["Multiple Transactions"](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/API%20Blueprint%20Specification.md#example-multiple-transaction-examples) in the API Blueprint specification.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the templates and specify a specific use case after a generic response for your resource, see example:

### Reservation [/reservation/{reservation_key}]

A Reservation object has the following attributes:

- room_number
- reserved_at - An ISO8601 date when the question was published.
- booker_details - A Booker Object.
- Parameters

  - reservation_key (required, text, `1`) ... Reservation Key ash

#### View a Reservation Detail [GET]

- Response 200 (application/json)

  ```
  {
      "room_number": 55,
      "reserved_at": "2014-11-11T08:40:51.620Z",
      "booker_details": 
          {
              "name": "Jon",
              "last_name": "Doe",
          }
  }
  ```

### Reservation [/reservation/notarealreservation123]

Using a non existing reservation (pls use `notarealreservation123` in the fake) returns not found